Identify an educational program where the speed of light is calculated with a cheese pizza
An episode or clip from a science program was shown to me in school where a group of people showed how you can calculate the speed of light using a cheese pizza in a microwave.
The technique was thus:

Place uncooked pizza inside microwave with the rotating plate removed.
After some time a specific circle of cheese on the pizza will have melted.
Using the radius or circumference of the circle of melted cheese (which was something do with the microwave wavelength) and the frequency listed on the microwave, you can calculate the speed of light.

The clip was shown to me around 2006–2009 but could have been a lot older.
At least 2 presenters were in the clip.
Seen in a UK school, and I believe the program was also using UK presenters.
The target audience was probably high-school science students.

Cant find anything specifically but this format reminds me of the old Standard Deviants (1996) series, if that rings any bells?

Could it have just been a youtube video? google search

In the UK - it might have been How 2 or The Big Bang

None of the linked videos have been it so far. I didn't manage to find a clip of How 2 or The Big Bang that fits either, though those names hardly help in a google search. Those two shows do seem familiar so it might be one of those.

I believe you're looking for BBC Royal Institute Christmas Lectures 1999 - Arrows of Time.
The experiment measures the speed of light using melted marshmallows.
